# Simple pendulum and irrational time period

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

The time period of physical pendulum is given by $T=2π\sqrt{l/g}$. 
I want to ask if $l=g$ in this case then $T =2π$ which is an irrational number. How do you account for this anomaly?

Comment: So ? ...Time period can be $3 s 1416... ms$ ...

Comment: Moreover, l=g is dimensionnally incorrect ; which means it can only be valid, by accident, with one specific set of units.

Comment: The period is how long it takes (usually in seconds) to make a full oscillation.  There is no reason to suggest it should be an integer or a rational number.

Comment: The circumference of any circle is irrational, but that is not usually a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your issue comes from the fact that pi has an infinite amount of digits, but this is true for any real number. If our period was 1 second then T = 1.00000... This then becomes an issue of how precisely we can measure something. In an ideal mathematical world there is nothing wrong with having an irrational period. In the real world we are limited by the instruments we use to measure things.

So if we were to actually create a pendulum whose length was "equal" to the gravitational acceleration at that location (this assumption is also limited by the precision to which we measure both of those quantities as well), then we would only be able to confirm that the period is $2\pi$ to the precision allowed to us by what we are using to measure time.

We also have additional problems with precision here since the given formula is derived from an approximation using the small angle approximation as well.

Comment: Pray explain how you propose to create a pendulum with length measured in $m/s^2$?

Comment: Also, note that the presence of $\pi$ in the equation itself makes it irrational (unless $g=\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)^2l$ where $n$ is a rational number), so its basically most of the time irrational only.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero that is why I put the word equals in quotation marks. I understand that a length can not actually be equal to an acceleration.

Comment: #aaron Stevens but in a theoretical sense the time period should be finite.

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja Having an infinite number of digits past the decimal point does not mean the time itself is infinite. pi is a finite number.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes that is what I am saying. I chose to attack the heart of the question rather than get into the details of the dimensions. I want to be helpful rather than try to appear smart and answer questions that were not asked.

Comment: #aaron Stevens I meant to say that since π is 3.14159...... i.e it is not a certain value that we can attach to time period .

Comment: #zerothehero I mean numerically if l=g and even if it is not equal than most of time it would be irrational due to radical sign.

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja I'm not sure I follow.  $\sqrt{4}$ is rational.

Comment: #zerothehero that's why I told most of the time (if l/g is not a perfect square) say l=1 m.

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja That is the point I am trying to make. In reality we could never actually measure any period, rational or irrational, to infinite precision to actually say it is some precise value. So with the math this is not a problem. Under the assumptions used to derive that formula, if we were to set up the experiment so that our length and gravitational acceleration divided to give 1 second squared, then the pendulum would oscillate with a period of 2pi. If we had an "infinite precision" clock this is what we would find as we looked to more and more decimal places.

Comment: #aaron Steven you meant to say that even we can't measure 1 second precisely(1.00000.....) which is the standard definition of 1 second.

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja This is just like how if we had 2 rods that were exactly 1 meter in length (which is not physically possible, but mathematically is) and set them as the legs of a right triangle, then a rod that is just the right length to form the hypotenuse of the triangle would be $\sqrt 2$ meters. If we were to measure the length of the hypotenuse with an "infinite precision" ruler, we would find that the length is exactly $\sqrt 2$ meters.

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja Exactly. In the real world we cannot say anything is precisely 1 second (unless we define a certain process to be such a thing)

Comment: #aaronstevens I know that what you are saying about length since in a similar manner π is defined as the ratio and ratio of two numbers is rational but since we practically can't draw a infinitely precise circle. But it is counter intuitive with time and even that 1 m is not practically possible

Comment: @SiddharthaRaja You are right. There is no way in the real world for a period to be precisely $2\pi$. We cannot measure anything with infinite precision. So whereas mathematically it is possible, physically it is not.

Comment: #aaronsteven I think it totally boils down to whether the 9,192,631,770 transitions of cesium-137 is precisely 1 second or not .since if it is exactly 1 second then there should be plausible answer to my query otherwise we should need to discuss about the definition of 1 sec.